# Laboratory Information System interface to Remisol 2000 Data Manager

Tags: .net, integration

I need to develop an interface between a Laboratory Information System (LIS), developed in .NET, and the Remisol 2000 Data Manager , which is a API for lab instrumentation systems made by Beckman Coulter Inc. The idea is to fetch the test results programatically into the LIS.

Are there any resources on the web that can give me a start ? I presume i need to open a Socket , but the documentation only mentions the message structures for the Protocols like Synchron LX20, Synchron CX7, ASTM, ASTMH2 and LIS Gen.S.

All of them use the Serial protocol.

```
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;

public class ClientToBeckmanDL2000
{
    static bool _continue;
    static SerialPort _serialPort;
    static bool keepRetrying = true;

    public static void Main()
    {

        CreateNewSerialPortAndOpenIt();

        SendAndReceiveMessagesInALoop();

        CloseTheSerialPort();
    }

    private static void CloseTheSerialPort()
    {
        _serialPort.Close();
    }

    private static void SendAndReceiveMessagesInALoop()
    {
        StringComparer stringComparer = StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase;
        string outputMessage, inputMessage;
        _continue = true;
        DateTime startTime, endTime;
        TimeSpan diffInSeconds;
        int retryCounter = 0;


        Console.WriteLine("Type QUIT to exit");

        try
        {
            while (_continue)
            {
                outputMessage = Console.ReadLine();

                _serialPort.WriteLine(
                        String.Format("{0}", outputMessage));

                if (outputMessage.Equals("ENQ") || outputMessage.Equals("<ENQ>") ||
                    outputMessage.Equals("EOT SOH") || outputMessage.Equals("<EOT> <SOH>") ||
                    outputMessage.Equals("<EOT><SOH>"))
                {
                    while (keepRetrying.Equals(true))
                    {
                        startTime = DateTime.Now;
                        inputMessage = string.Empty;

                        inputMessage = GetResponseFromServerInALoop();



                        endTime = DateTime.Now;
                        diffInSeconds = endTime - startTime;

                        // if the time for response crosses 15 seconds keep retrying
                        if (diffInSeconds.Seconds > 15)
                        {
                            retryCounter++;
                            keepRetrying = true;
                            Console.WriteLine("Retrying..." + retryCounter.ToString());
                            Console.WriteLine(" ");
                            if (retryCounter > 7)
                            {
                                keepRetrying = false;
                                Console.WriteLine("Tried more than 7 times . Line down. Please try again later...");
                                break;
                            }


                        }
                        else
                            if (inputMessage.ToString().Length > 0 && (inputMessage.Equals("STX")))
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Response is " + inputMessage.ToString() + " The Remisol server is bidding for line. Try to send your message later ... ");
                                keepRetrying = false;
                            }
                            else
                                if (inputMessage.ToString().Length > 0 && (!inputMessage.Equals("ACK") && !inputMessage.Equals("NAK") && !inputMessage.Equals("STX")))
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("Response is " + inputMessage.ToString() + " It should be ACK or NAK or STX. Try again ... ");
                                    keepRetrying = false;
                                }
                                else
                                    if (inputMessage.ToString().Length > 0 && (inputMessage.Equals("NAK")))
                                    {
                                        Console.WriteLine("Response is " + inputMessage.ToString() + " It should be ACK. Try again ... ");
                                        keepRetrying = false;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        Console.WriteLine("Please key in [00,800,01]97<CR><LF> to check Remisol..");
                                        keepRetrying = false;
                                    }
                        if (keepRetrying.Equals(true))
                        {
                            _serialPort.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}", outputMessage));
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                    if (outputMessage.Equals("[00,800,01]97<CR><LF>"))
                    {
                        do
                        {
                            inputMessage = _serialPort.ReadLine();
                            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                            keepRetrying = false;
                            Console.WriteLine(inputMessage);

                        } while (inputMessage.Equals(null));

                        Console.WriteLine("Response is " + inputMessage.ToString());
                    }
                if (stringComparer.Equals("quit", outputMessage))
                {
                    _continue = false;
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
    }

    private static string GetResponseFromServerInALoop()
    {
        string inputMessage = string.Empty;


        do {
            inputMessage = _serialPort.ReadLine();

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
            keepRetrying = false;
            Console.WriteLine(inputMessage);

        }
        while (inputMessage.Equals(string.Empty));

        return inputMessage;
    }

    private static void CreateNewSerialPortAndOpenIt()
    {
        _serialPort = new SerialPort();

        // Allow the user to set the appropriate properties.
        _serialPort.PortName = SetPortName(_serialPort.PortName);
        _serialPort.BaudRate = SetPortBaudRate(_serialPort.BaudRate);
        _serialPort.Parity = SetPortParity(_serialPort.Parity);
        _serialPort.DataBits = SetPortDataBits(_serialPort.DataBits);
        _serialPort.StopBits = SetPortStopBits(_serialPort.StopBits);
        _serialPort.Handshake = SetPortHandshake(_serialPort.Handshake);

        // Set the read/write timeouts
        //_serialPort.ReadTimeout = 0; -- this is being commented since this testing program needs to run for long time without timeouts. The default is anyway 0 which is infinite timeouts
        //_serialPort.WriteTimeout = 500000; -- this too is being commented out since it needs to run infinitely for test

        _serialPort.Open();
    }


    public static string SetPortName(string defaultPortName)
    {
        string portName;

        Console.WriteLine("Available Ports:");
        foreach (string s in SerialPort.GetPortNames())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("   {0}", s);
        }

        Console.Write("COM port({0}): ", defaultPortName);
        portName = Console.ReadLine();

        if (portName == "")
        {
            portName = defaultPortName;
        }
        return portName;
    }

    public static int SetPortBaudRate(int defaultPortBaudRate)
    {
        string baudRate;

        Console.Write("Baud Rate({0}): ", defaultPortBaudRate);
        baudRate = Console.ReadLine();

        if (baudRate == "")
        {
            baudRate = defaultPortBaudRate.ToString();
        }

        return int.Parse(baudRate);
    }

    public static Parity SetPortParity(Parity defaultPortParity)
    {
        string parity;

        Console.WriteLine("Available Parity options:");
        foreach (string s in Enum.GetNames(typeof(Parity)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("   {0}", s);
        }

        Console.Write("Parity({0}):", defaultPortParity.ToString());
        parity = Console.ReadLine();

        if (parity == "")
        {
            parity = defaultPortParity.ToString();
        }

        return (Parity)Enum.Parse(typeof(Parity), parity);
    }

    public static int SetPortDataBits(int defaultPortDataBits)
    {
        string dataBits;

        Console.Write("Data Bits({0}): ", defaultPortDataBits);
        dataBits = Console.ReadLine();

        if (dataBits == "")
        {
            dataBits = defaultPortDataBits.ToString();
        }

        return int.Parse(dataBits);
    }

    public static StopBits SetPortStopBits(StopBits defaultPortStopBits)
    {
        string stopBits;

        Console.WriteLine("Available Stop Bits options:");
        foreach (string s in Enum.GetNames(typeof(StopBits)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("   {0}", s);
        }

        Console.Write("Stop Bits({0}):", defaultPortStopBits.ToString());
        stopBits = Console.ReadLine();

        if (stopBits == "")
        {
            stopBits = defaultPortStopBits.ToString();
        }

        return (StopBits)Enum.Parse(typeof(StopBits), stopBits);
    }

    public static Handshake SetPortHandshake(Handshake defaultPortHandshake)
    {
        string handshake;

        Console.WriteLine("Available Handshake options:");
        foreach (string s in Enum.GetNames(typeof(Handshake)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("   {0}", s);
        }

        Console.Write("Stop Bits({0}):", defaultPortHandshake.ToString());
        handshake = Console.ReadLine();

        if (handshake == "")
        {
            handshake = defaultPortHandshake.ToString();
        }

        return (Handshake)Enum.Parse(typeof(Handshake), handshake);
    }
}
```

Comment: Define each type of protocol for each of the above, are they serial, tcp-ip based, x25 perhaps. Define that first.

Comment: Well the Synchron CX7 has a serial interface to it.

Comment: All of these are supposed to be using the serial protocol.

Comment: So you are saying they are all serial protocols. If that is so, I can answer the question.

Comment: The beckman technical documents website really crap.

Comment: Yes they are all supposed to be using serial protocol. However, when i connect my 'client' program and send a <ENQ> or <EOT><SOH> i do not get the ACK handshake reply. So i want to validate my client program by seeing some resources or LIS programs.

Answer (score 1):

I've done similar interfacing for a LIMS system to lab instruments (in my case, [thermocyclers](http://www.flickr.com/photos/trivelli/412667768/in/set-72157594573567964)).

I don't know about the specific instruments you mentioned, but many lab instruments use a serial interface of some form. The physical layer could be either rs232 (if the instrument is intended to exist standalone on a bench) or it could be rs485 (if there are multiple instruments that need to be ganged together in a "daisy-chain" configuration). The protocol level can be a pretty wide variety of simple message/response patterns. Some of these are actually standards (ASTM 1394), others are "home-made" jobs that consist of simple blocks of bytes with op-codes, data and a checksum. Whatever it is, you'll need good documentation if you don't have API libraries you can use. You might have to make phone calls to get this stuff, it isn't always available on the internet.

One of the problems that you'll have is that servers that run LIMS systems are often in a datacenter somewhere and your instruments are in a lab. To make it worse, the servers don't have serial ports, and the instruments don't have ethernet.

To get around this, you'll want to use "serial terminal servers" or "serial device servers" (for example... [link](http://www.quatech.com/products/sds.php)). These are little metal boxes that take ethernet traffic and route it to one or more serial ports (the ports can be configured as rs232 or rs422 or rs485). On the server, you install a driver that makes these ports on the remote terminal server appear as an actual ports to the server application. Alternatively, you can also choose to route data to/from a specific TCP/IP socket to a specific serial port.

If you get it to work, it is a pretty neat rewarding project that saves a lot of time. Good luck!

Comment: I have added the code of my client program to my question now. I am using a rs232 cable connecting client and server. The same client program works with a 'dummy' server program made to act like an ASTMH server. It fails when i plug it into the Remissol server PC and send the EOT SOH or ENQ messages.

Comment: You do realize that "ACK" and "STX" are actually ascii characters and not three letter strings, right?

Comment: Ok so instead of sending a string like ENQ and waiting for a string like ACK, i need to send ASCII of ENQ and expect ASCII of ACK ?

Comment: Yes, that's right. These are known as ascii control characters. Their values are defined in any ascii table (for example, search ASCII in wikipedia). Usually, these characters are written with angle-brackets to indicate that they are to be replaced with the ascii content. eg <ACK> means the ascii char with the value 0x06 in hex.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using an interface card like the ones provided by Data Innovations?
https://datainnovations.com/
All of the hospitals that use our LIMS system have these cards. They accept a text file of comma separated values (csv) for placing orders and output a text file with a similar format for results. The LIS doesn't need to know the interfacing specifics of the instruments, it just needs to create and parse text files.